# PHP rename error

Tags: php, rename

I get this error when using the rename function

```
Warning: rename(../data/feeds/feed2.txt,../data/feeds/feed3.txt) [function.rename]: No error in C:\wamp\www\cms\admin\pages\feeds.php on line 32
```

"../data/feeds/feed2.txt" is the correct path, I have done include("../data/feeds/feed2.txt") and it displays the file. And "../data/feeds/feed3.txt" doesn't exist.

Anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Does this happen to be on a Windows network share?

Comment: Check the destination file doesn't exist. If it does unlink() it.

Answer (score 0):

you should check if "../data/feeds/feed2.txt" is readable and if "../data/feeds/feed3.txt" is writable...

```
$oldname = '';
$newname = '';
if (
    file_exists($oldname)&&
    (
        (!file_exists($newname))||
        is_writable($newname)
    )
) {
    rename($oldname, $newname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in try-catch statements : `copy( $old_name, $new_name ); unlink($old_name);`

Just you must be sure that directory is writable.

In your case u must be sure that this destination file is exists or use absolute file paths

Answer (score 0):

Did you enclose strings in quotes?

```
rename('../data/feeds/feed2.txt','../data/feeds/feed3.txt');
```